dolphin crashes on ubuntu 24.04
dolphin crashes after trying to open Folders in a 2nd NVMe, not the boot one.
when sending report it return that they alredy new that.
Is there an alternative to dolphin?
I5 14th gen
32Go Ram
2 NVMe
thanks for answering

Take your pick https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4ldsj0/better_file_browser_than_dolphin_and_thunar/ and you can probably find more if you search on the web. This question is not actually for this forum.

Always open Dolphin with "Launch using the Discrete Graphics Card" option from the Dolphin icon's right-click menu if such an option exists.
